# how to store JSON response into cache while using Alamofire in Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, api, alamofire

Can anyone tell me the best approach to use cache while getting response from api.
I'am using Alamofire '4.7.3' and swift 4.2

Comment: try moya plugin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a JSON response, convert it into a string and save it locally. Parse back the objects using the Codable protocol.
Anyway the best approach would be to parse it into objects and then save the objects into CoreData (or Realm...)

Answer (score 1):

You can implement an internal database with CoreData to store your json and when you want parse it to create the objects you want

Comment: JSON is a transport protocol. It doesn't work well as a storage protocol. Too verbose, too heavy. One should store relevant data, not the incoming JSON stream.